# How to get the value of selected item in jQuery accordion and display it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using the jQuery Accordion with reference from [here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active).

On clicking the items in my section (header), I want to display in the below format:

Section # -> item # in my label as text (like breadcrumb).

I tried to search about it, and I got a clue to use

```
var active = $('.selector').accordion('option', 'active');
```

But I do not have idea oh how to use this. I am new to jQuery.

My code is below :

```
           $(function () {
                $("#accordion").accordion({
                    heightStyle: "content"
                });  
            }); 
        </script>  

                        <div id="accordion">
                            <h3>
                                Section 1</h3>
                            <div>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Item 1</asp:LinkButton> 
                                <br /><br />
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server">Item 2</asp:LinkButton> 
                            </div>
                            <h3>
                                Section 2</h3>
                            <div>
                                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">Item 3</asp:LinkButton> 
                                 <br /><br />
                                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server">Item 4</asp:LinkButton> 
                            </div> 
                        </div> 

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_selectedValue"  ></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code:-

```
$("#accordion").bind("click", function() {

    alert($("h3[aria-expanded='true']",this).text());

});
```

or

```
$("#accordion h3").bind("click", function() {

    alert($(this).text());

});
```

Comment: This is'nt working. I am getting a blank message box every time

Comment: @Vishwajeet: Thanks. This is what I was looking for, second one worked for me with jQuery - v3.2.1 and jQuery UI - v1.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

here

```
$('.selector').accordion('option', 'active'); 
 --^^^^^^^^^---this is accordion selector.. in your case it is <div id="accordion"> so use #accordion.
```

use `text()` or `html()` to replace the active value in `<label>`

```
 $('#lbl_selectedValue').text();
 --^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- label selector with id as lbl_selectedValue
```

try this

```
 $(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
                heightStyle: "content"
    });  

    var activeAccordion=$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
    $('#lbl_selectedValue').text($("#accordion h3").eq(activeAccordion).text()); //"OR $('#lbl_selectedValue').html(activeAccordion);

    $(".accordion-header").on("click", function() { 
         var activeClickAccordion=$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
         $('#lbl_selectedValue').text($("#accordion h3").eq(activeClickAccordion).text());
    })
 });
```

**updated**

give your label a class and try it..

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_selectedValue"  class="lbl_selectedValue"></asp:Label>
```

and your selector.

```
$('.lbl_selectedValue').text($("#accordion h3").eq(activeAccordion).text());
```

Comment: I tried using this. My accordion is not working and neither the code.All the headers are expanded and not collasible

Comment: still not getting the value to label. But Accordion is working. Thanks for your effort. Please let me know how to solve this

Comment: on page load the value is 0 and it remains the same when i click the items. I did what you have suggested.

Comment: on page load, i get "Section 1" in label. But it remains the same after clicking all the items. I need the Item name and the section name on clicking an item. This is the code, i have used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24102/discussion-between-anuya-and-bipen)

Comment: <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                heightStyle: "content"
            });

            var activeAccordion = $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active"); 
            $('.lbl_selectedValue').text($("#accordion h3").eq(activeAccordion).text()); 
            $("#accordion").on("click", function () { 
                $('#lbl_selectedValue').text($(this).accordion('option', 'active'));
            })
        });   
    </script>

Comment: change in click event too...` $('.accordion-header').on("click", function () { $('#lbl_selectedValue').text($("#accordion h3").eq(activeAccordion).text()); }) `

Comment: Same behavior as before : on page load, i get "Section 1" in label. But it remains the same after clicking all the items.

Comment: check the updated... `$(".accordion-header").on("click", function() { ....` part.. replace this code with your onclick this should work....